# Android: fill relative layout height (item layout) inside ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-relativelayout, fill-parent

I'm not able to make a `View` that fill the height of a `RelativeLayout`, which is the layout of `ListView` items. Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<View 
    android:id="@+id/fill_the_height_please"
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/red"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/delivery_list_item_dest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fill_the_height_please"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:text="Destinatario" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/delivery_list_item_address"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/delivery_list_item_dest"
    android:layout_below="@id/delivery_list_item_dest"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text="Location" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/delivery_list_item_mapBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/map_location"
    android:background="@null" />
```

View with id *fill_the_height_please* not fill the item height. In figure below you can see the result (nothing is shown):

[image]

I'd like something like this:

[image]ù

I have also try to change view layout as follows but not works anyway:

```
<View 
    android:id="@+id/fill_the_height_please"
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/red"/>
```

Please can you help to achieve my goal? Thank you.

Comment: There is no view with id `fill_the_height_please` in the layout for `ListView` item.

Comment: did you set color value in color.xml file?

Comment: Post your `color.xml` file.

Comment: sorry Onik, now it's correct.

Comment: color is a detail, you can use `@android:color/red`

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion would be add layout_alignTop="@+id/delivery_list_item_mapBtn" and layout_alignBottom="@+id/delivery_list_item_mapBtn" to the View and make it always fit the image height.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/delivery_list_item_statusBtn"
```

to

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fill_the_height_please"
```

You don't have delivery_list_item_statusBtn. But i see red part even without changing this. Try it and if it doesn't help please post code of your adapter.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I'va just correct the code. However i don't think the problem is the adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Looking [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) it seems `RelativeLayout` has a bug in version 17 and lower. So i have change my layout as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<View 
    android:id="@+id/fill_the_height_please"
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/red"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/delivery_list_item_dest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Destinatario"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/delivery_list_item_address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Location" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/delivery_list_item_mapBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/map_location"
        android:background="@null" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

A little bit more complex but works. However i leave the question unresolved in case someone find a solution using only a `RelativeLayout`